# регламент работы с gitlab

Tags: gitlab

каждую задачу веду в отдельном branch, после делается "merge request" и merge в dev ветку

первый коммит в новый branch, изза тестов, дал "commit failed"

вторым коммитом внес правки, второй коммит "passed"

но в "merge request" висит конфликт и кнопка "merge" задисейблина

подскажите штатное решение для подобной ситуации

(на locally конфликтов нет)